# Yii - Using i18n with CJuiDatePicker

Tags: internationalization, yii

I'm trying to make an internationalised Yii application.

I have a behaviour that translates dates to and from the users chosen locale date format so that's all handled fine.

When I try to set the language and date format for CJuiDatepicker from the locale settings, I end up with Chinese month names (no matter what locale format I pick), and US formatted dates.

The format that CJuiDatePicker wants for its dates and languages doesn't match what Yii provides - how do I make the picker work?

Comment: The widget has a `language` attribute, you don't have to write anything. For English use `en-GB` or `en-US` otherwise the two digit locale code will suffice . http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker#language-detail

Comment: thanks - unfortunately the language attribute doesn't use the same format as the Yii locale settings. Jon's answer clears it up tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with jQuery and Yii is that they don't both use the same locale names. For example Yii has locale names such as `en` and `en_gb` while jQuery does not have an `en` locale at all and calls the "English (United Kingdom)" locale `en-GB` (dash instead of underscore).

There's also the matter that Yii's and jQuery's date format specifiers differ.

To bridge the two worlds you 'll have to write some manual code; this is an excerpt from my own code that I 've used in a past project:

```
class LocaleExtensions {
    private static $yiiTojQueryFormatConversion = array(
        'yyyy' => 'yy',
        'yy' => 'y',
        'MMMM' => 'MM',
        'MMM' => 'M',
        'MM' => 'mm',
        'M' => 'm',
    );

    private static $yiiTojQueryLanguageConversion = array(
        'en' => 'en-GB',
    );

    public static function getJQueryDateFormat($width='medium') {
        return strtr(Yii::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat($width),
                     self::$yiiTojQueryFormatConversion);
    }

    public static function getJQueryLanguageFromYii($language = null) {
        if ($language == null) {
            $language = Yii::app()->getLanguage();
        }

        if (isset(self::$yiiTojQueryLanguageConversion[$language])) {
            return self::$yiiTojQueryLanguageConversion[$language];
        }

        return $language;
    }
}
```

To fix the locale issue, you can subclass Yii's widgets to do this at an opportune time (or just do it manually):

```
$this->language = LocaleExtensions::getJQueryLanguageFromYii($this->language);
```

You can also retrieve a jQuery-compatible date format from your Yii settings and use it in Javascript code like this:

```
var format = <?php echo json_encode(LocaleExtensions::getJQueryDateFormat('long'));?>
var locale = <?php echo json_encode(LocaleExtensions::getJQueryLanguageFromYii());?>
var now = new Date();
alert($.datepicker.formatDate(format, now, $.datepicker.regional[locale]));
```

Comment: That explains it, thanks. I was hoping there was A "Yii way" of doing things, but a helper class should work fine.